# Fluent nhibernate problem, query

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate.search, nhibernate-criteria

I'd really appreciate some help with a problem I have.

Class L holds a collection of R and R holds a collection of Q.
Each instance of R can be exists in multiple instances of L and each instance of Q can exist in several instances of R.

Everything is working fine except I have a function I can not figure out how to write.

I've a function that receives an instance/ object of R and Q. So with R and Q I'd like to query over L and find out where R is used. I would also like to find out if and where Q is used.

Thanks for information and help!

Answer (score 1):

Revised: fixed misstyping

```
R myR = ...;
Q myQ = ...;

var LsWithMyRandFlagIfQisUSed = session.QueryOver<L>()
    .JoinQueryOver(l => l.Rs)
    .Where(r => r.Id == myR.Id)
    .List<L>()
    .Select(l => new
    {
        L = l,
        QisUsed = l.Rs.Any(r => r.Qs.Contains(myQ)),
    });
```

Edit: added linq syntax havent testet

```
R myR = ...;
Q myQ = ...;

var LsWithMyRandFlagIfQisUSed =
    from l in session.Query<L>()
    where l.Rs.Contains(myR)
    select new 
    {
        L = l,
        QisUsed = l.Rs.Any(r => r.Qs.Contains(myQ)),
    });
```

Comment: It seams I forgot to answer here. Thanks for the attempt but I could not get that to work properly.

Comment: whats the problem? Maybe i can fix it

Comment: ah i see, i tried it with an example and rewrote it for your Names and had mistake

Comment: Ah thanks, gonna try it out. I'm new to queryover and have not yet had the time to fully understand it's syntax and perks with the stressed time schedule I've been under. I find it somewhat tricky.. to bad they just could not override linq / lambda..

Comment: they have also. just `using NHibernate.Linq` and you can use `from l in Session.Query<L>() where ...`